# Define an <img>'s src attribute in CSS

Tags: css, attributes, image

I need to define an <img>'s src attribute in CSS.  Is there a way to specify this attribute?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10247567/461499

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css

Answer (score 81, accepted):

```
#divID {
    background-image: url("http://imageurlhere.com");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: auto; /*or your image's width*/
    height: auto; /*or your image's height*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: @zipcodeman : That's too bad. There are some limitations to the `background-image:` method. Like, you have no control over the dimensions of the image. You can make the image space bigger, of course, just not the actual image.

Comment: @GregoryLewis I think this is better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css

Comment: @zipcodeman - You can change the size of the image this way by using `background-size:cover`, and then changing the height and width.

Comment: Today, 2017 year, `background-image` is not the solution. Making this, I have 2 images

Answer (score 283):

just this as img tag is a content element

```
img {
    content:url(http://example.com/image.png);
}
```

Comment: img hover too ?

Comment: Currently, Data URIs only work in Chrome. `content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='181' .....`

Comment: how is this not the accepted answer? today i think this is widely implemented in browsers

Answer (score 51):

No there isn't. You can specify a background image but that's *not* the same thing.

Comment: Indeed. `<img>` represents a content image. If the image isn't content then it shouldn't be an `<img>` element. If it is content, then it should be. If the content is duplicated on multiple pages (such as being part of a menu) then the HTML for it should be too (e.g. using a template system) just like any other duplicated content.

Answer (score 13):

CSS is not used to define values to DOM element attributes, javascript would be more suitable for this.

Answer (score 10):

No. The closest you can get is setting a background image:

```
<div id="myimage"></div>

#myimage {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white url(myimage.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

After trying these solutions I still wasn't satisfied but I found a solution in this [article](http://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/) and it works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE8+

```
#divId {

  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://notrealdomain2.com/newbanner.png) no-repeat;
  width: 180px; /* Width of new image */
  height: 236px; /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 180px; /* Equal to width of new image */

}
```

Comment: I was about to post the same article, it works perfectly for me, and I have to support IE on my site. if it works for IE...

Answer (score 2):

They are right. IMG is a content element and CSS is about design.
But, how about when you use some content elements or properties for design purposes?
I have IMG across my web pages that must change if i change the style (the CSS).

Well this is a solution for defining IMG presentation (no really the image) in CSS style.
1: create a 1x1 transparent gif or png.
2: Assign propery "src" of IMG to that image.
3: Define final presentation with "background-image" in the CSS style.

It works like a charm :)

Comment: It doesn't work if you need that `<img>` to print, which was the situation I'm in.

Comment: have you **1x1 transparent gif or png** for _download it_ ? any full sample with `html and css code` ?