# Change image source based on viewport width

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).resize(function(){
  var width = $(window).width(); 

   if (width < 361) {
      $(".infograph-image").attr("src","/images/infographicHowMobile.png");
   }
 }); 
</script>
```

I wish to change the image source of a given image, based on the viewport width size.
If the viewport width size is 360 or less, change to a mobile version of the image.

I have two simple questions:

1) 
How can we do both: a) detect windows resize AND document ready ?

This, I believe I got:

I need to change that into a function. 
Then call it on load;

```
checkResponsive();
```

Then bind a event listener:

```
$(window).resize(checkResponsive);
```

2)
We have several images that need to have a mobile version, should this be converted to a function ? Or several ifs may work ?

Can you please give me a kick-off start on those two questions please.

Comment: did you try $(window).resize() or css media queries?

Comment: @prashanth: window.resize is that I have on the code sample posted. Media queries, is there a way to change the img src using media queries ?

Comment: see the answers in http://stackoverflow.com/q/2676436/441860

Comment: I would say use media queries. also if you want you can do something like this also : http://jquerypicture.com/ it is a great plugin, just resize the window and you will understand it. I hope it helps\

Comment: @prashanth thanks a lot for your answer. However, that will not work. I'm totally aware of background image change using css, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah How the hell could media queries do the job here without javascript on the way ? Please, read my question properly and if in doubt I will do my best to clarify it.

Comment: @MEM my bad, but I think jquerypicture should do the trick. I think I gave answer about how to accommodate the same html code on smartphones and tablets for media queries but for resize event the plugin should do the trick

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah thanks. I have tried the script and, for some reason, I was unable to get the image to display inside my figure element. I was obviously missing something but I didn't get. I end up using another script that does the work much better then I would ever do. response.js

Comment: okay. I am glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a seperate function and call them on both events.
So, for example, create the function mobileImg() like this:

```
function mobileImg(targetClass, imageSrc) {
    var width = window.innerWidth; // No need for jQuery here, raw JS can do this

    if(width < 361) {
        $(targetClass).attr("src", imageSrc);
    }
}
```

And then call this on both events.

```
$(document).ready(mobileImg(".infograph-image", "/images/infographicHowMobile.png"));
$(window).resize(mobileImg(".infograph-image", "/images/infographicHowMobile.png"));
```

You can then call the `mobileImg` method as much as you want and with whatever params.
If you really want to make it clean, also add a check if the passed element and image exist at all and use fallbacks where needed.

Comment: I'm not getting this. If I have infographicHowMobile and infographicAboutMobile and infographicOtherImageMobile and infographicYetAnotherImageMobile, I need to call 8 times document.ready and window.resize ? :s

Comment: @MEM No, you would stack them in 1 call. Like: `$(document).ready(mobileImg(".class1", "img1"); mobileImg(".class2", "img2"));` and so on... Or pass targetClass/imageSrc as arrays to the function and loop over all of them.

Comment: @Oldskook - thanks a lot, I end up using the following very VERY nice script that does the job the same way I wished to have been done: http://responsejs.com/