# Change content in img through CSS

Tags: html, css, image

Relevant JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Efqda/

CSS -

```
.social img {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    opacity: .5;
}

.social img:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.social #facebook img {
    content: "https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-128-black.png";
}
```

HTML -

```
<a href="facebook.com"><img class="social" id="facebook"></a>
```

How do I get the image to show up? I don't get any errors in the console.

Comment: You shouldn't use an `img` tag if there's no `src`.  It confuses browsers.

Comment: Is it possible to specify the src through CSS?

Comment: Looks like a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182716/how-can-we-specify-src-attribute-of-img-tag-in-css/11484688#11484688

Comment: Not CSS, but you can with JavaScript if you must.

Comment: 7 answers and they are all wrong in some way. Surely someone will answer correctly soon...

Comment: @thirtydot Check my updated answer hope that the explanation is straight forward

Comment: @Ayush: Not quite. Try your demo in Firefox or IE, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix your code, first of all you would need to fix the selectors. For example, `.social img` means every `<img>` element which is a child of another (not the same) element with class `social`. Also all `id`'s must be unique so there is no need for `.social #facebook`, `.#facebook` is just enough.

However, this approach is flawed from the outset because using CSS to set the `src` of an `img` (`content: url("http://....");`) [only works in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12262118/1935077) (and other WebKit browsers).

---

You should use the following approach instead:

```
a[href="http://facebook.com"] {
    background: url("https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-128-black.png") no-repeat;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    opacity: .5;
    display: inline-block;
}
a[href="http://facebook.com"]:hover{
    opacity: 1.0;
}
```

with this HTML markup:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com"></a>
```

### [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Efqda/12/)

**See also:**

- [Define an `<img>`'s src attribute in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2676436/1935077)

Comment: This is now a reasonable answer. I zapped the first set of code because nobody should ever use it, since it only works in WebKit browsers and is overall a bad idea. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: @thirtydot - thanks for the cleanup of my post, there really is no need to post a code that doesn't work in all browsers. BTW, I'm not a native speaker so thanks again for the correction of the text.

Answer (score 1):

use the following

```
 img.social {
    background :url(/facebook-128-black.png) no-repeat;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `img.social`?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of issues, your CSS selector is wrong, if you have an id then just use that, also you need to specify that the content comes from an external source using url()

```
#facebook {
    content: url("https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-128-black.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img.social {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  opacity: .5;
  background-image:url(https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-128-black.png);
}
```

Also your link href is wrong.. it should be

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com">
   <img class="social" id="facebook">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Efqda/6/)

Please change your `.social #facebook img {...}` as `#facebook {...}`

Because you have to set image url to img tag id

And also change `contect:...` to `content:url("");`

Because you need to set content url from where you have to get image.

**Like**

```
#facebook {
  content: url("https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-128-black.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With css you just can to set bacground image.

With js you can set src attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your Issue was that you need to enclose your image URL inside `url()` in content and linking of CSS. Either use Class or ID but not both.

According to your style sheet `.social #facebook img`

there is a class `social` inside that there is an element with id `facebook` and inside an element `img`.

here you can see an example matching your CSS style.[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Efqda/8/)

and here is a straight **forward solution** [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Efqda/7/)

You can also use in-line CSS

```
<a href="facebook.com">
    <img class="social" id="facebook" style="content: url(https://raw.github.com/danleech/simple-icons/master/icons/facebook/facebook-128-black.png&quot;);"/>
</a>
```