# Changing the img in a nested alt tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

How can I programmatically change the following `img` in the structure below?

```
  <div id="runner" class="nav brand pull-left">
        <a alt="motherboard" href="/tree/">
            <img alt="mega node" src="img.png"></img>
        </a>
  </div>
```

firefox points me to this

```
#runner > a:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)
```

I've tried using standard methods as the following with various naming conventions

```
document.getElementById("#runner").src="icon.png";
document.getElementById("#runner.a.img").src="icon.png";
document.getElementById("#runner.img").src="icon.png";
document.getElementById("mega node").src="icon.png";
```

I've even tried css with no avail,

```
div#runner {
    content:url("img.png");
}
```

Comment: I think this is not how you use getElementById.

Comment: @Havenard I was following the example from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722400/programmatically-change-the-src-of-an-img-tag

Comment: Nah, `getElementById()` will select a DOM element by the specified `id`, and `id` only. I suppose you want to use `querySelector()` instead.

Comment: @Havenard ah i get it now, thanks, for science how would i do this with css?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676436/define-an-imgs-src-attribute-in-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your  are specifying argument in `getElementById()` in a wrong way, you should provide just an `id`, without selector `#`. You can find your `#runner` `div` and then find the first `<img>` tag in it and change it's `src` attribute :

```
  document.getElementById('runner').querySelector('img').src = 'icon.png'
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XnZT4/1/)

Or even simpler, without using `getElementById()` :

```
 document.querySelector('#runner a img').src = 'icon.png'
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/XnZT4/)