# Resize images from sprite

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to resize images which we receive from sprite.
I mean like this:

```
background: url(../images/sprite.png) no-repeat -1px -1170px;
display: block;
height: 14px;
width: 14px;
```

Is it possible to change width and height from sprite? For example if I have pencil icon in sprite with resolution 40x40 but I want to display this pencil icon like 20x20 pixels

Thank you, in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I scale an image in a CSS sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430206/how-can-i-scale-an-image-in-a-css-sprite)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `background-size` property in css3:

```
background-size: 50% 50%;
```

Comment: Your positioning will probably need to change since the sprite is now half the size.

Comment: Make positioning a percentage, and then it doesn't need to change.

Comment: @jacob Using Percentage combined with zmanc 's answer got me to where I wanted to be!! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 32):

Another solution is to use the `zoom: .5;` property of css3.

Comment: Boom! Works like a champ.  I only needed to support Mobile.

Comment: I wish I could have given you more up votes.   This is an old one but still very valid.

Comment: unfortunately not supported in firefox.

Comment: I think transform: scale(.5); /* 50% smaller */, would be better answer. As it supports everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Changing `background-size` will make you have to revalidate `width` and `height` of container every time.

When using `zoom` you will not have support for [firefox](http://caniuse.com/#search=zoom)

...

Another option is to use:

```
transform: scale(.5); /* 50% smaller */
transform: scale(1.5); /* 50% bigger */
```

The backside is that element after scaling will still keep its original space.

Answer (score 2):

After googling for this answer, I found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10826761/2100636

It worked in that it was responsive, although it is not using a background image to do it... it does work in all browsers as opposed to using the background-size option, where it would not work in old browsers - this method does.*

*well at least when I tested it.

You can see the demo here: http://tobyj.net/responsive-sprites/

I employed this in the situation where I have an icon on the left and text on the right, and it would scale my icon down to maintain responsiveness.

Answer (score 1):

**2018 solution:**

Lets say we have sprite of grid of 5X4.

First step is fixed the size of the background image relative to the continener

```
.sprite{ background-size: 500% 400%; }
```

now we have responsive sprite.

next is to use precente to position the background so just our figure will show up. the calculation are like that :

```
background-position: calc( var(--colum) * 100% / 5 - 1) calc(var(--row) * 100% / 4 - 1);
```

Now in every figure  we need to define on wich colum and row is position

```
.figure1{ --row:1, --column:0 }
.figure2{ --row:1, --column:1 }
// etc...
```

so togther we have :

```
.sprite{
     background-size: 500% 400%;
     background-position: calc( var(--colum) * 100% / 4) calc(var(--row) * 100% / 3); 
 }

.figure1{ --row:0, --column:0 }
.figure2{ --row:0, --column:1 }
.figure3{ --row:0, --column:2 }
.figure4{ --row:0, --column:3 }
.figure5{ --row:1, --column:0 }
// etc...
```

Nice demo with cards:https://repl.it/@perymimon/responsive-sprite

Full tab:  https://responsive-sprite--perymimon.repl.co/

Comment: Nice, but in your example u use a css grid sprite: all single images inside the sprite are equals for dimension. Can your solution be adapted to work also for sprites that contains images of various dimension?

Comment: if the sprite layout on some grid system I assume you can still work with that method just skip on some tiles. The main thing is that you can calculate the position with percent

Answer (score 0):

[`background-size`](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/) is what you are looking for.

```
#example1 {
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
#example2 {
    background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: This is close, but the sprite is almost definitely bigger than the specific icon he wants to shrink. if he shrunk the whole background to 20x20 his icon would be much too small.

Answer (score 0):

Using transform will only change the zoom of image not size. In order to change sprite image size from 40px by 40px to 20px by 20px, you need to change the size of sprite image to 20px by 20px and then adjust background-size to fit image sprite in that area. Also you need to adjust background-position in order to display correct portion of sprite.

```css
#home {
    width: 46px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
}

#next {
    width: 43px;
    height: 44px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) -91px 0;
}


#resizedHome {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) 0 0;
    background-size: 306%;
}

#resizedNext {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_navsprites.gif) -102px 0;
    background-size: 306%;
}
```

```html
<h5>
Original Sprite Image
</h5>
<img id="home" ><br><br>
<img id="next" >
<br><br>
<h5>
Resized Sprite Image
</h5>
<img id="resizedHome" ><br><br>
<img id="resizedNext" >
```

Or

https://jsfiddle.net/vivek11432/ep0m4yf6/

Comment: How do you calculate the new background size and the new position depending on the size to be transformed (46px -> 20px)?