# SVG scaled background jumps on zoom in / zoom out

Tags: css, svg, background, zooming

I want to show search icon properly for all views - with zoom / without zoom and normal view. 
Problem appears when people zooms for example 110%. Icon jumps.

Fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vx73L6ch/1/) ( try to zoom/zoom out - you will notice jumps )

HTML

```
<div id="outer">
  <div id="block"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer
{
    background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

#block
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(http://g3.acdn.lt/img/svg/icons_ptrn.svg);
    background-position: 0px 3.1%;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Tried:

- with and without background-position
- to set background position with pixels
- to set background position with percentages as it was suggested here: [background-size with background-position doesn't scale the position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033806/background-size-with-background-position-doesnt-scale-the-position)