# Set CSS background-size to be 'original' or '2x original', etc?

Tags: css

Im making a image sprite sheet. The icons need to be half the size on mobile so the background-size needs to be half of the original image.

Is the only way to do this to set the background-size property in PX?

In some instances the images need to be 3/4 or there original size so being able to specify the background size as a ratio of the original image would be quicker and make the code easier to read.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I scale an image in a CSS sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430206/how-can-i-scale-an-image-in-a-css-sprite)

Comment: My question isn't answered by any of those answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `background-size` for mobile is good option as [it's more widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=background-size).

You could set the background in percentage, if that's easier to read for you:

(1/2)

```
background-size: 50%;
```

(3/4)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
    background-size: 75%;
}
```

Comment: That % is relative to the element, not to the background image size which I what I need.

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify?

Comment: Background-size 50% will make the background be 50% of the size of the element its applied to. This isn't what I asked in my original question. Do you understand my original question?

Comment: I misunderstood somewhat. From what I can gather, background-size will be resized based on the element unless you specify in pixels.