# Is there a solution to sprite images on <li> that change in size?

Tags: css, css-sprites

I want to use sprites instead of bullets or `<img>` for my `<li>` but when the browser window resizes the `<li>` which is filled with text stretches and other sprite images bleed into view.

Is there a way around this problem without spacing out the images within the sprite to give enough space for the stretching `<li>`?

- I am not talking about scaling an image to go with font size changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scale an image in a CSS sprite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430206/how-can-i-scale-an-image-in-a-css-sprite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way around this I've found is not even a work around. It's to simply not use `<ul>` & `<li>` but recreate the look of a list and image with nested divs.