# CSS Sprite not sizing properly

Tags: html, css

I want to make the sprite into an icon at the top of the navbar but when I try to size down the sprite it cuts off the sprite and only sizes downs the box, how do I make it so the image sizes down and the box? I have tried moving the sprite to fit but it doesn't go down in size.

HTML below

```html
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
    <img class="sprite logo1">
</a>
```

CSS below

```css
.sprite {
    background: url('images/css_sprites.png') no-repeat top left;
}

.sprite.logo1 {
    background-position: -500px 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430206/how-can-i-scale-an-image-in-a-css-sprite

Comment: use `background-size` instead using width and height.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scale an image in a CSS sprite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430206/how-can-i-scale-an-image-in-a-css-sprite)